# Multiple Workflows on SP 2010 List Item

Tags: designer-workflow

I have developed an Incident Reporting site for a client that has multiple workflows attached to a list.  There are 11 total workflows here that email out various stages of an Incident.  There are also associated user workflows that setup a column with all users associated with the Incident.

I developed this separately, and with a column that flags when the notification is sent.  When each notification is sent, I updated the list item to the notification won't be sent again.

similar to:

If IncidentAwaitingApprovalNotification = "Yes"
        Email user
        then Update List Item Current Item: IncidentAwaitingApprovalNotifcation = "No"

The problem with this approach after awhile I noticed is, on this update, it turns around and fires all 10 other workflows AGAIN.

This creates loops, it creates multiple workflows firing at the same time and a lot of issues.

I've read online about using set instead of Update List Item, that set doesn't fire the event listener again to fire another workflow.  Is this true?

Currently these workflows are taking over 15 minutes to complete on items.. Sometimes longer.

What would be the best approach to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried action `Set Field in Current Item`?

Comment: that's what I'm trying now.  I'm wondering if this is the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could merge the workflows into one. You can create sort of a switch construction by using parallel blocks with if clauses for each state. This is quite robust and will even work when going back to a previous state.

Comment: I was thinking of doing that.. as it seems even when using set field in current item runs all of the workflows again.  any other ideas as I would have to develop each workflow again.. or export them all out to visio and modify the xml directly.

Comment: Perhaps at the beginning of each workflow check if it is the one that should run? I usually use a column in the list for an integer that defines the overall progress when working with multiple workflows. Shouldn't take much effort to add this sort of thing.

Comment: I do that, I have a column that is set to determine if the notification should be sent out.  If not the workflow ends after that If statement.  But the set field in current item still triggers the workflows to run again.